# finding listview column index using simple key string

Tags: c#, listview

I've assigned descriptive names to each of 4 columns in my ListView: Head, Mouth, Nose, Eyes.  How can I access these columns using that text?  I would love to find a way to do it as elegantly and concisely (with a  #define) as is done in C:

```
if (Column[MOUTH] == 6)...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very elegant, but this should work (in this example I get the text from the first selected item in the listView. You can also use listView.Items)

```
 string selectedItemMouthColumn = listView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[listView.Columns.IndexOf(MOUTH)].Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Include a key for the column when you create it. E.g.:

```
// C# - first string is column key, second is column title
MyListView.Columns.Add("Name","File Name");
MyListView.Columns.Add("Size","File Size");
```

You can then use the key string to get the column index.

```
var ColIndex = MyListView.Columns.IndexOfKey("Size");
```

alternatively:

```
// Example: Get name for first selected listview item:
ListView lv = MyListView;
string FName = lv.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[lv.Columns.IndexOfKey("Name")].Text;
```